# Android : Old foreground notification getting replaced by new one

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, foreground

I'm having some trouble getting multiple notification to show. I am getting a unique ID every time I start a new ForegroundService, so theoretically it should be showing separate notifications..?

```
private var id: Int = -1

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    id = intent.getIntExtra(PARAM_ID, -1)

    showNotification()

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

private fun showNotification(){

    createNotificationChannel()

    val openMainActivityIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        openMainActivityIntent.action = "ACTION"
        openMainActivityIntent.putExtra(PARAM_ID, id)

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, openMainActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelName)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(content)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    startForeground(callId + 10, notification.build())
}

companion object {
    private const val notificationChannelName = "channelName"
    private const val PARAM_ID = "PARAM_ID"

    fun startService(context: Context, id: Int) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val intent = Intent(context, MyForegroundService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(PARAM_ID, id)
            context.startForegroundService(intent)
        }
        else {
            val intent = Intent(context, MyForegroundService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(PARAM_ID, id)
            context.startService(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried only using one `Notification` for the foreground service and raising the others conventionally, using `NotificationManager`? Note that users may not appreciate multiple notifications.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have thought about it, the thing is these notifications have to do with calls, and users might have multiple calls at the same time. e.g. one call on hold and another in progress. These foreground services are linked to the lifecycles of the calls, they get killed when the call does, I kind of need multiple notifications to easily access any of the current calls that are in progress

Comment: "These foreground services are linked to the lifecycles of the calls" -- have exactly one foreground service for your app, not more than one. That foreground service is tied to the aggregate lifecycle of all outstanding calls.

Comment: @CommonsWare Alright, but how would the user open a specific CallFragment in this case? Say I want to access the call on hold, or alternatively the call in progress. One foreground service can handle multiple ongoing notifications, right?

Comment: "One foreground service can handle multiple ongoing notifications, right?" -- presumably, yes. Personally, I have not tried having multiple foreground services running at once. If you are saying that you are trying that, and even with N foreground services you only get 1 notification, then you also have to deal with the possibility that those other services do not get foreground treatment. If that is the case, then stopping the "real" foreground service might cause you to have zero foreground services, and your app's process will be terminated after a minute on Android 8.0+.

Comment: That is why I would try my best to have just a single foreground service, and have that service live so long as you have any outstanding calls. You might need to treat the one `Notification` that you use with `startForeground()` as special, always keeping it going so long as the service is, changing its contents as needed to reflect a different call than it used to represent. Your scenario seems valid but is on the fringe of conventional apps, and so you may run into problems, both for Android in general and on devices from manufacturers who are aggressive about terminating apps.

Comment: You are right, I just had a look on how the native call app works, it seems to use only one foreground service, the switching between calls is handled  in-app while the notifications content is updated based on which call is in progress. Thank you for the input! I will try to find a solution based on all of this. Thank you!